# How to save m2m field on Django with commit=False?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'd like to be able to save m2m fields, but I'm having an issue where I face this error :

> ValueError: : "..." needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Here's my **models.py** :

```
class Font(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    font = models.ManyToManyField(Font)
    ...
```

I am using modelForm for the many to many field. I get my values with ajax, here's what it looks like on `(pdb) request.POST` :

```
<QueryDict: {'fonts': ['2', '5', '6'], 'organisation': ['COMPANY'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...']}>
```

what's inside `'fonts'` are the id of `Font`.

**views.py**

```
...
    save_it = form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.organisation = request.POST.get('organisation')

    for font in request.POST.getlist('fonts'):
        fonts = Font.objects.filter(id=font)
        save_it.font = fonts.first().id #error on save_it.font

    save_it.save()
    save_it.save_m2m()
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ['organisation', 'fonts']
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What goes wrong when you simply do form.save()? Can you show the error with backtrace? Or is there no error, but relations aren't created either?

Comment: @Melvyn it saves everything except the m2m field, no relation. The error comes on save_m2m()

Comment: What is generated for the form's "fonts" field? Does it generate a formset? If so, your ajax does not transmit it's [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

Comment: @Melvyn the form m2m field is in this format, `'fonts': ['2', '5', '6']` This is why I'm using `commit=False` to be able to fetch the `id` of each object and  `save()` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move forward, I think it's best to remove the 'fonts' field from the form. It does not understand how to process it and you probably are not using the HTML generated for it, given how fonts are transmitted.

Your view code would then be something like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save()
    for font_id in request.POST.getlist('fonts'):
        obj.font.add(Fonts.objects.get(id=font_id))
```

Comment: `obj.font.add(Fonts.objects.get(id=font_id).first().id)` after `save()` is what I needed. Just a small correction, obj.font does not expect a queryset.

Comment: But get() doesn't return one. Did you do filter()?

Comment: Yes I did. Django is asking me to use either way the object id or name

Comment: Here's the [gory details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add). But id's work too. Whatever is more readable for you.